# File Name issue with RollingFileAppender in Log4net

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

I have implemented `RollingFileAppender` to log my ASP errors and it works fine. 
Now I need to change the file names based on the date value. Currently my log file name is `MyLog.log`, it's max size is 1 MB and maxBackup is 10. Now I want my log files with date like `MyLog_2011-12-29` for each day. I tried the below settings, but it's not appending the date value to the file name and it just creates the file as `MyLog`. Any suggestions?

**EDITED**

```xml
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\\xxx\\ASPErrors\\LogFile"/>     
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <eventId value="5" />
  <eventCategory value="ErrorLogging" />
  <datePattern value="_yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>  
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you have the "staticLogFileName" property twice in the config, the second one is overwriting the first.

Comment: Thats helpful. But one thing is my current file name is just MyLog without any extension. The rollbacks are having ".log" extension.

Comment: yea, I am running into this same issue now, it seems like the staticLogFileName option is not working as that is supposed to control whether or not the datePattern gets appending to the current file.  I will let you know what I find.

Comment: Its working fine now.In  my configuration i accidently added the below line twicw.Once i removed it ,it works fine and i updated the config above.<staticLogFileName value="true"/>

Comment: Very good, while I was testing this, I forgot to change my FileAppender to a RollingFileAppender, (which explains why it wasn't working for me).  Glad you got it working.